# Retry and Catch on AWS Step Function task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

For StepFunctions, can we have both `Retry` and `Catch` working together on the exhausted case?

Here is my use case

1. Job fails
2. Retry
3. Retries exhausted, goes to Catch
4. Catch all errors, move to next job, and update the DB table to mark this job failed (another task)
5. Or on success from 1st time run or retries, move to the next job

```json
    "ExecuteMyJob": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
            "Parameters": {
                "JobName.$": "$.jobName",
                "Arguments.$": "$.jobArguments"
            },
            "Retry" : [{
                "ErrorEquals": [ "States.TaskFailed", "States.Runtime" ],
                "MaxAttempts": 3,
                "IntervalSeconds": 60,
                "BackoffRate": 2
            }],
            "Catch": [{
                "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
                "Next": "MarkJobFailOnDbTable"
            }],
            "Next": "NextJobOnPreviousSuccess"
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step Functions lets you have both `Retry` and `Catch` together:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html

The Complex retry scenarios example in that link is similar to your example:

```
"X": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:task:X",
   "Next": "Y",
   "Retry": [ {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "ErrorA", "ErrorB" ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 1,
      "BackoffRate": 2.0,
      "MaxAttempts": 2
   }, {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "ErrorC" ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 5
   } ],
   "Catch": [ {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
      "Next": "Z"
   } ]
}
```